# unir data frames con columnas de distintos tipos en python

Tags: python, pandas

imagina que tenemos 2 df, un df0:

```
0   Importe Propina Sexo Dia    
1    11.24   1.76    1    6 
2    22.82   2.18    1    4 
3    48.33   9.0     1    2     
4    17.51   3.0     2    1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

y un df1:

```
    Dia Nombre
0   1   Lunes
1   2   Martes
2   3   Miércoles
3   4   Jueves
4   5   Viernes
5   6   Sábado
6   7   Domingo
```

tengo que unirlos usando la función merge, creando una nueva columna que se llame "Nombre" con el dia correspondiente segun el numero de dia en el df0 y el nombre en el df1.
Al hacer:

```
pd.merge(df0 ,df1 ,on = "Dia", how = "inner")
```

Me devuelve:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

lo primero es que debo usar la funcion merge, y por mucho que pruebe cambiando el tipo con .astype("int) me devuelve este error:`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Importe'`
 y eliminando del df0 la primera fila con los nombres haciendo:

```
pd.merge(df0[1:] ,df1 ,on = "Dia", how = "inner")
```

me siguen saliendo errores, por favor una ayudita me vendria muy bien ;)

Comment: Hola Jose, he creado una respuesta pero me acabo de dar cuenta de un detalle, en `def0` tienes `0   Importe Propina Sexo Dia`  , parece como si las cabeceras no fueran tal, sino una fila más (primera fila) ¿es así o es un error al pegar aquí los datos del DF? Si es así algo mal haces a crear el dataframe. El problema es el mismo que comento en mi respuesta, pero habría que hacer un paso extra para corregir el tema de las cabeceras... ¿Qué te muestra `df0.head(1)` y `df0.columns`?

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que **`Dia` en `df1` es de tipo `object` (seguramente son cadenas, tipo `str` nativo de Python)**. Tu uso de `pandas.DataFrame.merge` es totalmente correcto.

Podemos reproducir tu error de forma simple con:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data0 = io.StringIO("""\
Importe Propina Sexo Dia    
11.24   1.76    1    6 
22.82   2.18    1    4 
48.33   9.0     1    2     
17.51   3.0     2    1""")

data1 = io.StringIO("""\
Dia Nombre
1   Lunes
2   Martes
3   Miércoles
4   Jueves
5   Viernes
6   Sábado
7   Domingo
""")

df0 = pd.read_csv(data0, sep="\s+", engine="python")
df1 = pd.read_csv(data1, sep="\s+", engine="python")
df1.Dia = df1.Dia.astype(str)
```

> ```
> >>> df0.dtypes
>
> Importe    float64
> Propina    float64
> Sexo         int64
> Dia          int64 # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
> dtype: object
>
> >>> df1.dtypes
>
> Dia       object   # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
> Nombre    object
> dtype: object
> ```

Intentemos el merge:

> ```
> >>> pd.merge(df0, df1, on="Dia", how="inner")
> ```

consecuencia:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "<ipython-input-7-326dcdc07ffa>", line 1, in <module>
>     pd.merge(df0 ,df1 ,on = "Dia", how = "inner")
>
>   File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 68, in merge
>     op = _MergeOperation(
>
>   File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 630, in __init__
>     self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
>
>   File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1138, in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys
>     raise ValueError(msg)
>
> ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
> ```

La solución es simplemente convertirla a escalar, `pandas.to_numeric` es adecuada para ello por ejemplo.

```
df1.Dia = pd.to_numeric(df1.Dia)
pd.merge(df0, df1, on="Dia", how="inner")
```

> ```
>   Importe Propina Sexo    Dia     Nombre
> 0 11.24   1.76    1       6       Sábado
> 1 22.82   2.18    1       4       Jueves
> 2 48.33   9.00    1       2       Martes
> 3 17.51   3.00    2       1       Lunes
> ```

también puedes usar `pandas.Series.as_type` como intentabas, pero sobre la columna problemática solo:

```
df1["Dia"] = df1["Dia"].astype(int)
```

o:

```
df1["Dia"] = df1["Dia"].astype(df0["Dia"].dtype)
```

Puedes aplicar `pandas.DataFrame.astype`, pero debes usar un diccionario y especificar el tipo de cada columna, teniendo en cuanta que generas una copia del DF completo:

```
pd.merge(df0, df1.astype({"Dia": df0["Dia"].dtype}), on="Dia", how="inner")
```

Posiblemente se pueda corregir antes, en la creación de `df1`, pero para eso habría que saber de dónde y cómo sale.